# include .html files from different folders using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, include

I got a jQuery script that includes .html files from an includes folder into my index.html, and it works just fine.

```
var includes = $('[data-include]');
jQuery.each(includes, function(){
  var file = 'includes/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
  $(this).load(file);
});
```

I've encountered a problem when I try to include the same .html files but this time I am in a subpages folder trying to achieve the same result, but nothing gets included.

Folder structure:

```
index.html
assets
includes
   -login.html
   -header.html
subpages
   -contact.html
```

index.html

```
        <!-- Include search-bar.html -->
        <section class="login" data-include="login"></section>

        <!-- Include header.html -->
        <header class="logo" data-include="header"></header>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

contact.html

```
        <!-- Include search-bar.html -->
        <section class="login" data-include="login"></section>

        <!-- Include header.html -->
        <header class="logo" data-include="header"></header>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/lib/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be relative to the root directory, start the URI with a /

var file = '/includes/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';

try it.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought on the matter too, but I've tried it and it does not work. That even messes up things with index.html, so the includes does not work there aswell.

Comment: document.location.hostname +  '/includes/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html'; might works

Comment: make a console.info() of the string it generate and check if the route displaying is the correct ones

Comment: Thanks a lot for that one. Didn't knew it existed.

Well, this was highly disturbing... I tried, just for funzies, to switch to another editor and everything works when changing to '/includes/'. 

So, I guess the code works when I access the folder from root. 

Thanks for the help!